# Removing default menu in Video Player

Tags: android

I am using a video player in my app in which i dont want the default options like play, stop and progress seek bar when i click the video since i am going to stream a live video on that.Can anyone help me how to remove that.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call [`VideoView#setMediaController(MediaController)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html#setMediaController%28android.widget.MediaController%29), with `null`:

```
myVideoView.setMediaController(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how you implemented your player:
Take a look at the `VideoView` class with all its nice methods - [click](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html)

Comment: Thank you Mr.Martin the legend.